# Are there private questions now? (aka why "Public" for tagged questions?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, wording

In the Tagged Questions view (e.g. [support](/questions/tagged/support)), the title is:

> [image]

Or in words:

> **Public** questions tagged [*tag name her*e]

Emphasis mine. What does the word "Public" imply? Aren't all questions public anyway? Does it mean there are private questions somewhere now?

Comment: This is a bug. I have a related question on MSO. It's not intentional and will be fixed eventually. [Search results on MSO don't need to specify "Public" - do they?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369326/4548692)

Comment: @Catija thanks, [relevant comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369326/search-results-on-mso-dont-need-to-specify-public-do-they#comment599264_369326) for those too lazy to search. :) (heh, you added link too!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(An update wasn't provided here on MSE after the bug was fixed, hence the answer.)

---

This was fixed on June 19, 2018, with a [reply from Joe Friend](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369736/11206537) on the MSO post:

> This is now fixed on SO for all non-team members and on other sites for everyone.